Best practice for fetching API data asynchronously from different endpoints with React?
I am learning React for a project at work and currently really having trouble getting the hang of the asynchronous model.
Here is the component I'm working on:
const Customers = () => {
    const [logos, setLogos] = useState([]);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    const [titlePrompt, setTitlePrompt] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        // create a customer client object 
        const client = new Client();

        // query for the customer list and save name and token
        if (customers.length === 0) {
            client.get_customers().then((res) => {
                const customer_info = res.map(customer => {
                    return {
                        'name': customer.customer_name,
                        'token': customer.mqtt_customer_token
                    }
                });
                setCustomers(customer_info);
            });
        }

        if (customers.length > 0) {
            const fetched_logos = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                client.get_site_by_type(customers[i].token, 1).then((res) => {
                    const new_logo = {
                        [customers[i].name]: res.logo 
                    };
                    fetched_logos.push(new_logo);
                });
            }
            setLogos(fetched_logos);
        }

        setTitlePrompt("Select A Customer Shown Below");
    }, [customers, logos]);

    /**
     * button handler to transition to a dataframe view of the chosen customer via token
     * @param {defining} token 
     */
    const onButtonClick = (token) => {
        navigate('/dataframe', { state: { token } });
    };

    return (
        <div className={'mainContainer'}>
            <div className={'contentContainer'}>
                <div className={'titleContainer'}>
                    <div>{titlePrompt}</div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <ImageList cols={4}>
                    {customers.map(customer => (
                        <ImageListItem key={customer.name}>
                            <img alt={customer.name} src={`data:image/png;base64,${logos[customer.name]}`}></img>
                        </ImageListItem>
                    ))}
                </ImageList>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Customers;

What I'm trying to do is fetch customer information such as name and logo and display them in an ImageList.
The problem is, first I have to fetch the name and token (used for subsequent API calls) for each customer from one database, then I need to fetch the logos one by one since they all reside in specific customer databases. I want to render the component with only the img component's alt text and then populate the images as they come in. I just can't figure out how to synchronize this correctly inside useEffect. I also don't know if using the if statements to control what gets executed during subsequent useEffect calls is the right thing to do or just hacky.
I tried chaining .then but the setState calls are asynchronous so it leads to race conditions and doesn't work.
Thank you for reading.
EDIT:
Here is a code snippet showing my attempt with chaining .then:
client.get_customers().then((res) => {
            const customer_info = res.map(customer => {
                return {
                    'name': customer.customer_name,
                    'token': customer.mqtt_customer_token
                }
            });
            setCustomers(customer_info);
        }).then(() => {
            for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                client.get_site_by_type(customers[i].token, 1).then((res) => {
                    const new_logo = {
                        [customers[i].name]: res[0].logo
                    }
                    setLogos([...logos, new_logo]);
                });
            }
        });


Use two effects, with the state mutated by the first as a dependency of the second.

"I tried chaining .then" - that should also work, can you show us what exactly you tried?

@Bergi Can you elaborate on this? So the first useEffect makes the get_customers call with no dependencies then the second makes the get_site_by_type calls inside a loop with customers as a dependency? Could you maybe explain how/why this works?

"calls are asynchronous so it leads to race conditions and doesn't work" - you have (regardless whether chaining then or using separate effects or else) a problem with the client.get_site_by_type calls in the loop: the setLogos(fetched_logos) call doesn't wait for any of them. You'll need to use Promise.all there (or update the state after each individual response, but that's more complicated)

"Could you maybe explain how/why this works?" - it works more or less the same as your current code, just without "using the if statements to control what gets executed during subsequent useEffect calls" which is indeed rather hacky

@Bergi I've edited the post with a snippet showing my attempt to chain .then. With that code, logos gets all funky with the first entry being undefined and a bunch of duplicate entries.

Ah, yes, the individual setLogos([...logos, new_logo]); updates are the problem (as logos is always the empty array), the then itself is working fine. Again, I recommend to use Promise.all, but you could also do setLogos(oldLogos => oldLogos.toSpliced(i, 1, new_logo));

@Bergi Sorry but I still don't quite understand how to put this all together....would you be willing to share a code snippet?

Pet peeve:  I really don't like asking for "best practice" in so many words.  Just ask "How can I fetch API data asynchronously from different endpoints with React?" and define as many requirements as you need to ensure it's "best" (satisfies all your requirements).

Two problems, one is that state variables do not update as soon as you call the set function.  Better is to use the variable that contains the received data (here, I return customer_info so it can be used in the then, rather than calling setCustomers and then expecting the const customers to have been updated, which it will not have been).
Second problem is that you need to use promise.all or similar to sync it properly.
Untested illustrative code:
client.get_customers().then((res) => {
  const customer_info = res.map(customer => {
    return {
      'name': customer.customer_name,
      'token': customer.mqtt_customer_token
    }
  });
  setCustomers(customer_info);
  return customer_info;
}).then((customer_info) => {
  const promises = customer_info.map(customer => 
    client.get_site_by_type(customer.token, 1).then((res) => {
      const new_logo = {
        [customer.name]: res[0].logo
      }
      return new_logo;
    })
  );
  Promise.all(promises).then(logos => setLogos(logos));
});


I tried this, it all seemed to make sense to me, except I had to add a return statement before that client.get_site_by_type call because my linter was yelling at me for not returning something in the .map call. Now it's stuck in an infinite loop. I really don't understand what's happening...it's so hard for me to visualize

The infinite loop was due to a missing dependency array. Adding an empty dependency array fixed it.

Yes the map part needs either an implicit or explicit return.  My example has an implicit return.

Here is the working component:
const Customers = () => {
    const [logos, setLogos] = useState([]);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        // create a customer client object 
        let client = new Client();

        // query for the customer list and save name and token
        client.get_customers().then((res) => {
            const fetched_customers = res.map(customer => {
                return {
                    'name': customer.customer_name,
                    'token': customer.mqtt_customer_token
                }
            });
            setCustomers(fetched_customers);
            return fetched_customers;
        }).then((fetched_customers) => {
            const promises = fetched_customers.map(customer => {
                return client.get_sites_by_type(customer.token, 1).then((res) => {
                    const new_logo = {
                        'name': customer.name,
                        'logo': res[0].logo
                    }
                    return new_logo;
                })
            });
            Promise.all(promises).then((logos) => {
                setLogos(logos);
                console.log(logos);
            })
        })

    }, []);

    /**
     * button handler to transition to a dataframe view of the chosen customer via token
     * @param {defining} token 
     */
    const onButtonClick = (token) => {
        navigate('/dataframe', { state: { token } });
    };

    return (
        <div className={'mainContainer'}>
            <div className={'contentContainer'}>
                <div className={'titleContainer'}>
                    <div>Select a customer</div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <ImageList cols={4}>
                    {customers.map((customer) => {
                        const logo = logos.filter(logo => logo.name === customer.name)[0]?.logo ?? '';
                        return (
                            <ImageListItem key={customer.name}>
                                <img alt={customer.name} src={`data:image/png;base64,${logo}`} />
                            </ImageListItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </ImageList>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Customers;

I first get the customers and set those. Then I use .then to retrieve an array of all promises returned by fetching each individual logo by calling .map. Then I use Promise.all to set all the logos once all the promises have resolved. I also changed the way logos are stored by giving them a name and logo key so that they can be properly referenced in the .map call inside the ImageList. The filter call inside the the ImageList simply ensures that the img src is empty if there is no logo to be found.

This answer needs a clearer explanation of what you've changed. Code without an explanation or additional commentary isn't very useful.
